# eclipse file search: How to search within workspace also in non project folders

Tags: linux, eclipse, file-search

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0) on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
I have many git repos in my Eclipse workspace, but only a few of them are Eclipse projects (due to many colleagues aren't using Eclipse as IDE). The problem is the file search feature of Eclipse: It seems that the search in only in "Eclipse projects" folders performed! Is there as simplme way to let Eclipse search in **all workspace folders**?
Thanx!

Comment: As far as Eclipse is concerned folders which are not in projects are not part of the workspace and it will not search them.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse _File Search_ searches only in opened projects. As workaround, you can link the folders into a project (e.g. into an existing project or into a new general project), to make everything in it visible inside of Eclipse. By the way, you are using an outdated version. File search performance has been improved since then and there is the new _Quick Search_.

Comment: Thanks @howlger! This workaound is a good tradeoff for me! I created a new lightweight general project and added my non-ecplipse-folders as linked folders. Works fine! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I noticed a big disadvantage of such a "search only project": Normally I worked with the git perspective. And if I open a file in the top of the windows the file path is given as searchProject path. This would be no problem, BUT: If I change the file, the " repos changed indicator" '>' is missing and also if I try to commit the change! No Change is seen by the git plugin! :-( So I had to dlete the search folder and try another possibility....

Comment: @GO12 Git repositories are handle only on project level: if the project directory is contained in a working tree of a Git repositories, the project will show the Git information. Independent of that, in the _Git Staging_ and _Git Repositories_ view, a _Refresh_ might be required to see the changes.

Comment: @howlger maybe but I have the other way round: I cloned many git repos in into the Eclipse workspace and added them in the git repositoriers view. With usage of my "search only projert" if I altered a file there was no changes symbol (">") at the git repo root. Even if I refreshed (F5). Even the git staging view didn't show the file changes! So, unfortunately, these are no goes